# Storing password in config file - best practice

Tags: passwords

I am configuring an application server hosted on EC2 instance to send e-mail notifications.

This requires configuring SMTP settings and storing them, including password, in a config file:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "mail.example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "username@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = 'password'
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "mail.example.com"
```

Is storing plaintext password really bad? If an attacker gets inside they can do some damage anyway. Still I'd like to make it as secure as possible so I am wondering what's the best approach and best practice.

Comment: Hashing the password would be smart, but you need the full connection string password for the connection...

Comment: Thanks @SirMuffington, turns out this particular application - Gitlab - can read settings for certain features from encrypted config files. Should be easy to set up.

Answer (score 2):

> Is storing plaintext password really bad?

As always answers to such questions in the context of security is - it depends on the treat model.

Regarding the credentials - based on the excerpt of the config file you provided it appears that you are configuring a Gitlab server. The Gitlab allows using the encrypted SMTP credentials as described in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#using-encrypted-credentials):

> Instead of storing the SMTP credentials in the configuration files as
> plain text, you can optionally use an encrypted file for the SMTP
> credentials. To use this feature, you first need to enable GitLab
> encrypted configuration.
>
> The encrypted configuration for SMTP exists in an encrypted YAML file.
> By default the file will be created at
> /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/encrypted_configuration/smtp.yaml.enc.
> This location is configurable in the GitLab configuration.
>
> The unencrypted contents of the file should be a subset of the
> settings from your smtp_*' settings in the gitlab_rails configuration
> block.